# Rockset -- Could not find a module declaration for module './rest/index'. ../../rest/index.js has implicitly type any

Tags: node.js, typescript, typescript-typings, rockset

I have been looking through all of the other posts about the same issues in react/typescript projects but none of these have worked for me...not even changing noImplicitAny to false and strict to false is ts.config or setting the "excludes" and "typeRoots".

I've tried declaring a module, I've tried putting it in a .d.ts file, I've tried using @ts-ignore, I can't get anything to work. It's driving me crazy...can somebody tell me how to resolve this once and for all so I can get this to compile properly?

There are a whole lot more issues of the same type in the index.js file but once with a ton of requires throwing the same issue but once I can resolve this, I should be able to fix the others as well...

```
    (function(factory) {
  if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
    // AMD. Register as an anonymous module.
    define(['rest/index'], factory);
  } else if (typeof module === 'object' && module.exports) {
    // CommonJS-like environments that support module.exports, like Node.
    module.exports = factory(require('./rest/index')); **<---- ERROR HERE**
  }
}(function(restIndex) {
  return restIndex;
}));
```

EDIT:
**Client.js:**

```
var apiKey = process.env.ROCKSET_APIKEY;
var apiServer = process.env.ROCKSET_APISERVER;
var rockset = require('rockset')(apiKey, apiServer);

var getResponseLogger = function(callback) {
    return function(error, response, body) {
        if(error) {
            console.log(error.response.error.text);
            callback();
        } else {
            console.log(response);
            callback();
        }
    }
}

export function getMaxSkill() {
    rockset.queries.query({
        'sql': {
            'query': 'select * from "testCollection"'
        }
    }, null, getResponseLogger(done))
}

function done() {
    console.log('\n\n===done===');
}
```

**App.tsx:**

```
import {getMaxSkill} from './client';

async componentDidMount() {
   getMaxSkill();
}
```

**tsconfig**

```
  {
      "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "lib": [
          "dom",
          "dom.iterable",
          "esnext"
        ],
        "allowJs": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "strict": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "module": "esnext",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "isolatedModules": true,
        "noEmit": true,
        "jsx": "preserve",
        "typeRoots": [
          "../../@types",
          "../../node_modules/@types"
      ]
      },
      "include": [
        "src", "tests/App.test.js"
      ],
      "paths": {
        "@material-ui/core": ["./material-ui/src"],
        "@material-ui/core/*": ["./material-ui/src/*"],
        "@material-ui/lab": ["./material-ui-lab/src"],
        "@material-ui/lab/*": ["./material-ui-lab/src/*"],
        "@material-ui/styles": ["./material-ui-styles/src"],
        "@material-ui/styles/*": ["./material-ui-styles/src/*"],
        "@material-ui/system": ["./material-ui-system/src"],
        "@material-ui/types": ["./material-ui-types"]

      }
    }
```

Comment: I would suggest you upload an minimal github repo that reproduces your problem, as this kind of question tends to depend on the structure of the entire project.

Comment: don't see how that is possible...it's based on the react-create-app with hundreds of node_modules involved.  This is the only one throwing an error however, everything else was working fine and compiling without issue until I installed this module.

Comment: You don't need to include the node_modules folder in your repo (add it to .gitignore); those who download it will install the modules themselves.

Comment: basically all you need to do to reproduce it is npm install react-create-app and npm install rockset using typescript

Comment: If that's all I do, I certainly will not have a ./rest/ folder in my project.

Comment: you will because npm install rockset creates one in its node_module directory

Comment: OK, I think we're getting somewhere... So what you're showing above is the rockset.js provided in that module. Would you care to show us how exactly are you using that module in your code, and what error did you get?

Comment: I assume you mean `async function componentDidMount()`; other than that, I don't encounter any error when compiling these two files (client.js and app.tsx). Can you show us your tsconfig.json?

Comment: really strange...I can't get anything to work in terms of compiling

Comment: I don't know; I simply cannot reproduce your error.

Comment: thanks for trying to help...I just went the REST API route using axios and got it working...rockset said they are going to be working on releasing @Type definitions

Comment: They just released typescript definitions!